# How does the Swedish healthcare system work for non-EU citizens?

Tags: health, sweden

I'll live in Sweden for two years, doing my master's degree. According to [this](https://studyinsweden.se/life-in-sweden/health-insurance-and-medical-care/), it seems like I'll be entitled to all the Swedish healthcare system and pay Swedish patient fees.

How does this patient fee work? How much does it cost? Should I get a private healthcare other than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patient fee varies depending on if you visit a primary health care provider or an emergency room, and can also vary between different parts of Sweden. The fees are very low though; usually vary between 100-300 SEK. You pay either with a credit/debit card, cash, or they send you a bill. There is also a cap at 1800 SEK for the maximum amount you pay for health care and prescription meds during a year. Private health care is generally not necessary. With private insurance, you will get care faster for non-emergencies such as knee replacements that are not prioritized by the national health care.

Comment: note: this does not apply to dental care. Had to go to emergency dentist and payed ~1200 SEK for a short 30 minute treatment.

Answer (score 2):

As a visitor I went to emergency care in a hospital in Sweden. They simply came to me with some paperwork and I paid with a debit card.
Ask your university if it is recommended to buy supplemental insurance. My guess would be however, that the fees are intended to be affordable to all Swedish people so therefore, pretty cheap.